# GNU find delete files within a directory but keep the directory itself

Tags: linux, command-line, grep, command-line-tool

I've been spending the better part of an afternoon trying to figure this one out.    I have a directory that contains several project directories, and within each project directory there is a `node_modules` directory.  I'd like to delete all files *hidden* included within the `node_modules` directory but **keep** the `node_modules` directory, ie. have an empy `node_modules` directory.

I've constructed a couple quasi solutions, but none seem to preserve / keep the `node_modules` directory.  I'm using GNU `find` and `grep` on macOS 10.12.x via homebrew with fish shell.

Comment: Do you want to delete __only__ the "hidden" files (in Unix, a file whose name starts with a `.` is _hidden_) with `node_modules` or do you want to delete _all_ files within  `node_modules`?

Comment: @John1024 **all** files within `node_modules`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To delete all files within any directory that is under the current and is named `node_modules` while keeping `node_modules`:

```
find . -path  '*/node_modules/*' -delete
```

(This was tested with GNU `find` but I expect that BSD/OSX `find` will behave similarly.)

#### Example

Let's create a `node_modules` directory with some files in it:

```
$ mkdir -p node_modules/dir{1..3}
$ touch node_modules/file{1..3}
```

Now, let's see what files this `find` command returns:

```
$ find . -path  '*/node_modules/*'
./node_modules/dir3
./node_modules/dir1
./node_modules/file3
./node_modules/file2
./node_modules/file1
./node_modules/dir2
```

This shows the files *inside* `node_modules` but *not* the `node_modules` directory itself.  Thus, we can delete the files with:

```
$ find . -path  '*/node_modules/*' -delete
$ ls
node_modules
```

Comment: thanks dude  and as stated above in my question I have GNU `find` installed via homebrew. 